# OpenGL wont render a square properly

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to render a colored square in OpenGL using glBegin(GL_QUADS) but for some reason it renders the square with an extra vertex in the middle. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATg4D.png). Am I doing something wrong or do I have to use a different method for 2d rendering?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

v = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
s = (0, 1, 2, 3)


def c():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for vertex in s:
        glColor3fv((1, 1, 1))
        glVertex2fv(v[vertex])
    glEnd()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (1500, 1000)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(50, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 5000)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -8.5)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        c()
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the indices is wrong:

```py
v = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
```

<s>`s = (0, 1, 2, 3)`</s>

```py
s = (0, 1, 3, 2)
```

You need to order the indices around the quad:

```non
2          3
 +<-------+
 .        ^
 .        |
 .        |
 +------->+
0          1
```

---

Alternatively you can change the order of the vertices:

```py
v = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))
s = (0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think of that.